# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded when using react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to change all of my source code from using react with redux to react-hook with redux and connect It with firebase:

This warning occured when I redirect to localhost:3000/blogs,

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a 
component calls 
setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency 
array, or one of the 
dependencies changes on every render.
in BlogDashboard (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.jsx:32)
in Switch (at App.jsx:31)
in div (created by Container)
in Container (at App.jsx:30)
in Route (at App.jsx:27)
in App (at src/index.js:44)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:40)
in ReduxFirestoreProvider (created by ReactReduxFirebaseProvider)
in ReactReduxFirebaseProvider (at src/index.js:39)
in Provider (at src/index.js:38)
```

in Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
         <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}> // firebase worked fine
             <BrowserRouter>
                    <ReduxToastr timeOut={2000} preventDuplicates position="bottom-right" 
                                transitionIn="fadeIn" transitionOut="fadeOut" />
                    <App />
             </BrowserRouter>
         </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
     </Provider>, 
     document.getElementById('root');
);
```

in App.jsx:

```
const App = () => {
const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth, []);
if(!auth.isLoaded && auth.isEmpty) return <LoadingComponent />

return (
    <Fragment>
        <ModalManager />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
        </Switch>
        <Route path='/(.+)' render={() => (
            <Fragment>
                <NavBar />
                <Container className="main">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/blogs' component={BlogDashboard} />
                        <Route path='/blogs/:id' component={BlogDetailedPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </Container>
            </Fragment>
            )} 
        />
    </Fragment>
    );
}
```

In BlogDashboard.jsx:

```
const BlogDashboard = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const firestore = useFirestore();

const blogs = useSelector(state => CastToArray(state.firestore.data.blogs) || []);//this worked fine
const moreBlogs = useSelector(state => state.blogs.moreBlogs);
const loading = useSelector(state => state.async.loading);

useEffect(() => {
    const getBlogs = async () => {
        await dispatch(getPagedBlogs({firestore}));
    };

    if(blogs.length === 0) {
        getBlogs();
    } else {
    }
}, [dispatch, firestore, blogs]);

const handleGetNextBlogs = async () => {
    await dispatch(getPagedBlogs({firestore}));
};


return (
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <BlogList blogs={blogs} loading={loading} moreBlogs ={moreBlogs} getNextBlogs= 
                                                                         {handleGetNextBlogs} /> 

        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <Loader active={loading} />
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
    ); 
};

export default BlogDashboard;
```

in BlogActions:

```
export const getPagedBlogs = ({firestore}) => 
async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(StartAction());
    const LIMIT = 5;
    let nextBlog = null;

    const {firestore: {data: {blogs: items}}} = getState();

    if (items && Object.keys(items).length >= LIMIT) {
        let itemsArray = objectToArray(items);
        nextBlog = await firestore.collection('blogs').doc(itemsArray[itemsArray.length - 
         1].id).get();
    }

    let query = await firestore.get({
        collection: 'blogs',
        limit: LIMIT,
        where: ['date', '<=', new Date()],
        startAfter: nextBlog,
        storeAs: 'blogs'
    });

    if(query.docs.length < LIMIT) {
        dispatch({type: MORE_BLOGS});
    }
    dispatch(FinishAction());
};
```

in BlogReducer.js:

```
const initialState =  {
    blogs: [],
    moreBlogs: true,
};
export const moreBlogs = (state) => {
    return {
        ...state.blogs,
        moreBlogs: true
    }
}

export default createReducer(initialState, {
    [MORE_BLOGS]: moreBlogs
});
```

in BlogList.jsx:

```
const BlogList = ({blogs, moreBlogs, getNextBlogs, loading}) => 
<Fragment>
    {blogs && blogs.length !== 0 && 
         //Load blogs, using 'react-scroll-infinite'.
        <InfiniteScroll pageStart={0} loadMore={getNextBlogs} hasMore= 
  {!loading && moreBlogs} initialLoad={false}> 
            {blogs && blogs.map(blog => (
                <BlogListItem key={blog.id} blog={blog} />
            ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
    }
</Fragment>

export default BlogList;
```

I understand what the warning is trying to say, but not much experience with react hook.

Comment: Seems like you are doing setState inside render method. Try using setState outside render

Comment: Where are you setting state? None of the code you have presented shows where you are using your firestore data and setting it to state. I'm assuming this is inside `BlogList`. Please show us where you use `setState`

Comment: @JoshPittman, thanks for reminding me, I updated my post. Currently I don't use any setState method in react, I just create a intialState in blogReducer and the blogs is an empty array.

Comment: I get the data from firestore by using  "const blogs = useSelector(...)", which is declared in BlogDashboard.jsx, the blog list worked fine

Comment: Great. Please accept answer added below so that it helps other people who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the code you have presented shows where you are using your firestore data and setting it to state. Use setState to actually store the data in your react app.